# Updating the value of a hidden input with the data-id of a clicked on <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, hidden

I have created a form which contains simulated dropdown menu with subdropdowns, created using a foreach loop through a @Model. When I click on one of my , I want value of my hidden input field to equal the data-id of the clicked on

What I had got so far - HTML

```
     <form id="myForm" method="post">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.User);

                    <div class="yourstats" id= "yourstats">
                        <h3>Your Stats</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <div class="yourteam">
                            <h3>Teams</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">

                            <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Team 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <div id='Team1' class="dropdown-menu">
                                    @foreach (var member in Model.Team1Members)
                                    {
                                        <a href="#" data-id="@member.Key">@member.Value</a>

                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Team2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <div id='Team2' class="dropdown-menu">
                                    @foreach (var member in Model.Team2Members)
                                    {
                                        <a href="#" data-id="@member.Key">@member.Value</a>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>

</form>
```

This is the function I am trying to use to grab the dataid from the clicked on  and put it in the hidden input . It works fine when I hardcode the data-id for testing purposes, like so -

```
`$(".dropdown a").on("click", () => {
   var $value = 7909
   $('#User').val($value)
   $('#myForm').submit()
});`
```

but I cant make it work without the hardcoded value

```
    `$(".dropdown a").on("click", () => {
    var $value = $(".dropdown a").data("id")
    $('#User').val($value)
  $('#myForm').submit()
});`
```

Chrome dev tools is telling me that when I use the hardcoded values, I am sending the correct ID = 7909 to the server. But when I try to use my actual function, I am not sending any data to the server. So that means the problem is in this part of the code, right?

```
`$(".dropdown a").data("id")`
```

I had a very good look at other questions that involved selecting a data-id and or updating the value of a hidden input, and they informed my work so far but no dice.
I'm sure I'm doing something very simple wrong, can anyone tell me what it is?

EDIT: I have also tried

```
`$('.dropdown a').attr('data-id')`
```

and

```
`$('.dropdown a').data('data-id')`
```

with no luck, and same error.

Comment: have you tried using $('.dropdown a').attr('data-id')  to read the value of the "data-id" attribute?

Comment: you are getting the "id" attribute instead of the "data-id" ..maybe your confusion is because you are using the "data" function...:P..that does not add "data" to the attribute name, you know?..lol...

Comment: Yes, I have tried $('.dropdown a').attr('data-id') @daddygames, I will update that to my post

Comment: Since you are using an arrow function, there is no concept of "this." Part of your problem may be that you need to know which control is the sender to this function so that you can read the data-id attribute from the sender element. It may benefit you to move away from arrow function to $('.dropdown a').on('click, function(){ var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); //.. other logic });

Comment: Thank you @daddygames you solved it! I can't give you a star though because you posted as a comment not an answer. Make a comment and I will give you a star

Comment: good to hear. I've added my comment as an answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using an arrow function, there is no concept of "this." Part of your problem may be that you need to know which control is the sender to this function so that you can read the data-id attribute from the sender element. It may benefit you to move away from arrow function to:

```
$('.dropdown a').on('click', function(){ 
   var $value = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $('#User').val($value)
   $('#myForm').submit() 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your html example

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a data-id=1 value="volvo">Volvo</a>
    <a data-id=2 value="saab">Saab</a>
</div>
```

Here's your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown a").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));
    });
});
```

Focus on **$(this).attr("data-id")** is what you are looking for

Comment: Both you and @daddygames gave me the same correct answer so thank you very much but I saw theirs first so I'm gonna make theirs as a solution, but thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS approach using an arrow function and capitalizing on the fact that every event handler gets passed the event object which has a property `target` that holds a reference to the originating element of the event:

```js
document.querySelector('.dropdown').addEventListener(
  'click',
  e => { if (e.target.dataset.id) dataid.value = e.target.dataset.id }
)
```

```css
span[data-id] { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <span data-id=1 value="volvo">BMW</span>
    <span data-id=2 value="saab">Porsche</span>
</div>
<input type="text" id="dataid" />
```

Please note that I have chosen to replace the `a` element with a `span`. An anchor is not the correct element to use here. Always easy to spot when you don't have an `href` to set.